# How to Structure Private Route in React

Tags: reactjs

I created a privateRoute component, just to route guard my users like so:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  return user ? <Route {...rest} /> : <Redirect to={"/login"} />;
};
```

In my App.tsx

```
<Box h="78vh" as="main" display="flex" alignItems="center" mt={3}>
      <Container maxW="container.lg">
        <Switch>
          <Route component={Home} path="/" exact />
          <PrivateRoute component={Dashboard} path="/dashboard" exact />
          <Route component={Login} path="/login" exact />
          <Route component={Upload} path="/upload" exact />
        </Switch>
      </Container>
    </Box>
```

Public Route

```
export const PublicRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  restricted,
  ...rest
}: any) => {
  const { user} = useAuth();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        user && restricted ? (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

index.tsx [Entry]

```
  <Router>
    <Navbar />
    <App />
    <Footer />
  </Router>
```

It When i wrap my PrivateRoute on the Dashboard, it does not redirect to dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are excluding the `component` prop and only passing the rest of the props to the `Route`. You can either:

- Keep all the props and pass them to `Route`:

```
export const PrivateRoute = (props: any) => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  return user ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to={"/login"} />;
};
```

- Or pass the `component` prop that you get during the destructuring:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  return user ? <Route component={component} {...rest} /> : <Redirect to={"/login"} />;
};
```

It really depends on whether you want to do anything in particular with the `component` prop other than passing it to the `Route` component.

Comment: How about the Public Route sir? please check question

Comment: I don't get your comment, there is no mention of an issue with the public route in your initial question. Can you explain?

Comment: Check question now sir

Comment: You could follow the same structure you did for the private route as follow: `return user && restricted ? <Redirect to={"/login"} /> : <Route component={component} {...rest} />;`